# Recipe for target failed error in Eclipse using cygwin

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, cygwin

First of all, I know that this question already exists multiple times in Stackoverflow but the answers provided for all of them didn't solve my issue(See section "Solutions worked for others" at the end of this question).

I am using the Eclipse IDE(Juno) with CDT plugin and Cygwin installed in my Windows-7 64-bit platform.

I successfully compiled and run the Hello World 'C' program but the Hello World "C++ program" is having **Launch failed. Binary not found** error.
I am also having **recipe for target project.exe failed** error in my auto-generated makefile.

```
Error line in makefile:  @echo 'Building target: $@'
```

Additionally:

In c/c++ build -> toolchain editor ->

Current toolchain : Cygwin GCC

Current Builder  :    Gnu Make Builder

Used Tools:

- GCC Assembler,
- GCC Archiver,
- Cygwin C++ Compiler,
- Cygwin C Compiler,
- Cygwin C Linker,
- Cygwin C++ Linker.

When I change Current Builder from "Gnu Make Builder" to "CDT Internal Builder" the **recipe for target project.exe failed** error disappears but the **Launch failed. Binary not found** error still exists.

And also I dont have MinGW installed.

### Solutions worked for others :

- Before running the project directly using the run command, first Build the project and then run.
  **I build the project every time before I run it.**
- Eclipse can't find or point to an .exe file but the exe file runs fine when run from windows explorer and the answer to it is add -arch i386 to miscellaneous under linker.
  **My build runs without error but not creating the exe file. So this doesnt apply to me**
- Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Binary Parsers
  set "Cygwin PE Parser" and/or " PE Window Parser" and alike.
  **Tried all of them with different combinations but did not work**

I also did :

- **adding the cygwin install dir to the path variable**
- **added all the includes folders needed for cygwin for both GNU C and GNU C++ in Paths-and-Symbols -> includes**
- **Saved the project before building and then running**
- **restarted eclipse again**
- **checked if g++ is installed using which g++ in terminal**
  and so on.

What could be a fix to this problem? Or do I have to install MinGW (I tried already to install MinGW with the installer.exe they provided and it failed on downloading the files several times) and try again.

I couldn't find the solution. Please show me what am I missing here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've just run into the same issue for an .elf build with GNU ARM Eclipse Neon.2 on Win10. For me it was a linker error (two static variables with same name within different modules but same scope) that didn't get marked as an error (so I looked past it when searching for a solution).

Comment: Check is the exe file exists. In my case it actually created the exe and I could run it from explorer, but eclipse claimed the file does not exist. I had fix path in debug configuration.